# Curve right side shape of block

Tags: css, shapes

Is this possible to make with CSS3? (right side of the block)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can, but you should not ... Better SVG

Comment: How I can? I tried... Can't use it as pseudo-elem cause ugly gradient.

Comment: 'better' SVG in what way @Air this can easily be done with transforms, shadows, clip paths etc. I think OP should include what they have coded already so we aren't assuming how they are doing it

Comment: I haven't SVG, that's the part of png...

Comment: Please provide more context, what kind of element is this? Do you have an HTML environment where you want this desired behaviour to work?

Comment: Full shape above

Comment: This is a very broad question and there are many many possible solutions. We would like to narrow down what specific issue you are having with getting this done @Epitaph Can you provide any relevant source code you can provide? Because based off the title alone, the answer is just ... yes, yes it can be done

Comment: What many solutions do you mean? Border radius doesn't help me and to add it through pseudo cause it has precific gradient. So what solution without svg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not perfect on colours etc. But the code below should give you a decent starting point.

```css
#parallelogram {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: skew(-25deg);
  background: red;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#4DD2FA, #387AFE);
}
```

```html
<div id=parallelogram></div>
```

Comment: It deformate inside content, that's what happenwith pseudo
http://prntscr.com/mko04i